# Floating Point Number storage in c

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

The Following is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( void )

{
    double dInput = 0.7;        
    printf("\n %.17f ",dInput);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is `0.69999999999999996` instead of `0.7`

can anyone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Its probably the same problem as in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck; No. That's different issue.

Comment: It is extremely strange that you get `0.6999999`. You should get `0.69999999999999996`, with perhaps, if you are using an inferior C implementation, only some variation in the last decimal digit.

Comment: I wish people actually looked at the linked question before closing as duplicate... That question is about usage of `float` vs. `double`.

Comment: @interjay; Agreed with you. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @interjay What “that” question are you talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary is about “Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?”, which is about how this question should be phrased.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; The link you are talking about is right but the the duplicate marked link is not explaining this issue anyway.

Comment: @interjay This ought to be marked as a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230869/tiny-numbers-in-place-of-zero).

Comment: @haccks I fail to understand the rationale behind voting to reopen this.  Agreed that the question being referred to doesn't answer _this_ the best, there are scores of questions that answer __this__ very problem.  I'm certain that you'd have answered it several times.

Comment: @devnull; Yes right. But I am disagree with wrong close votes. If this question will reopen then I will vote again to close it with its right dupe. By the way I have flaged it for moderator attention.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871086/float-variable-doesnt-meet-the-conditions-c/19871124

Comment: this is the 1000001th question about floating point in this site

Comment: I foud a great explanation on wiki in the section: **[Accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)**

Comment: @haccks Your link does not include deleted questions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; What? I do not understand. Which deleted questions?

Comment: @haccks Bad StackOverflow questions get deleted. You cannot see these questions through your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point . There is no reason to think that a significant proportion of floating-point questions that were asked were not deleted. It certainly feels like 1000000. (Also, some identical questions are asked without the floating-point tag)

Comment: @PascalCuoq; I was not aware about the deleted ones (deleting my comment). When could I see that?